# ByteViewer Control in Winform, get ANSI value of the given input

Tags: c#, winforms, ansi

There is a [ByteViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer(v=vs.110).aspx) Control directly available in the .NET Framework.
How do I get the data in a ANSI format from this control and assign to a string variable?

My input will be in hexadecimal form.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by "my input will be in hexadecimal form". The ByteViewer takes *bytes* as input, what does "hexadecimal form" mean? If you are converting a string of hex characters to bytes first, you might want to include that in the question statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to convert the bytes to a string using the C# Encoding class. I'm assuming ANSI is ISO-8859-1.

```
var bytes = byteViewer.GetBytes();
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
string result = encoding.GetString(bytes);
```